# Is it possible to launch an android app using an url with POST parameters

Tags: android, post

If I use the following `Activity` declaration in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
        <data android:host="my.app" android:scheme="http"></data>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

`http://my.app` will launch the `Activity`.

**BUT** what if I do a `POST` on that url? Is there a way to get the `POST` parameters from the `Activity`?

Comment: I would expect the answer here to be browser-dependent.

Comment: @CommonsWare: why? do you think the request would be modified before being intercepted by Android?

Comment: I tried it, "http://my.app" didn't launch the app in any browser !

Comment: No, it's more that while I think `GET` behavior is well defined, I'm betting that `POST` behavior is not.

Comment: @MohsenAfshin: I copy paste the answer from another question, it should work.